# woocommerce add to cart functions

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to figure out where these functions are called within the woocommerce product loop:

```
function woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart()
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart()
```

These functions load the 'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' template and the 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php' template, respectively.

I thought the content-product.php template might call these functions, but this template goes directly from:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

to

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

The template for the shop loop item itself must be generated somewhere else in woocommerce.

Comment: php are smple text files, so you can copy them to any folder and search them with an texteditor like pspad

Comment: you can find it here https://wp-kama.com/filecode/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php#L57

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but the search only found the functions being created in the wc-template-functions.php file and the functions being hooked in the wc-template-hooks.php file.  My guess is they are called with a variable for the product type, but a search for "woocommerce_"*"_add_to_cart" returns just about every woocommerce file.

Comment: pspad searches all files content and as search pattern should be woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title it would find all files hat have that

Answer (score 0):

The simple and variable add_to_cart functions that load the templates:

'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php'

and

'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php'

are called by the 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' function with a variable in the function name, like this:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $product->get_type() . '_add_to_cart' );
```

The 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' function is hooked to the 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' function which is called in the template file 'content-single-product.php' here:

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
</div>
```